# Symfony2 two step validation

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I have created entity called Proposal (in PHP using Symfony2) with several parameters like $proposalFile, $shippingProposalDate and many others.

None of them should be blank. But I need to let users to save this form even they don`t fill all required fields.
At the end of form is last checkbox called proposalDone. Once user marks proposal as done I need to validate all fields not to be blank.

Is possible in Symfony2 validate filled fields and blank not to. After marking proposal as done validate all and check whether user didn't forget anything.

Comment: If you allow user to save a form anyway, why to mark any field required?

Comment: Imagine you are in business process where you don`t konw all fields  during filling in. You fill few of them and when customer sends you response you fill the rest.